# Sorting string vector using integer values at the end of the string in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a directory containing files `{"good_6", good_7", "good_8"...,"good_660"}`, after reading it using **readdir** and storing in a vector I get `{"good_10", "good_100", "good_101", "good_102"...}`.

What I want to do is to keep the file names as `{"good_6", good_7", "good_8"...,"good_660"}` in the vector and then replacing first name with 1, second with 2 and so on... such that good_6 will be 1, good_7 will be 2 and so on. but now good_10 corresponds to 1 and good_100 to 2 and so on.

I tried std::sort on vector but the values are already sorted, just not in a way that I desire (based on integer after _). Even if I just get the last integer and sort on that, it will still be sorted as 1, 100, 101...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to define customize your sort method....Do you apply that?

Comment: put inline code into `\`backticks\`` to make it readable

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom function that compares strings with a special case for digits:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int natural_string_cmp(const char *sa, const char *sb) {
    for (;;) {
        int a = (unsigned char)*sa++;
        int b = (unsigned char)*sb++;

        /* simplistic version with overflow issues */
        if (isdigit(a) && isdigit(b)) {
            const char *sa1 = sa - 1;
            const char *sb1 = sb - 1;
            unsigned long na = strtoul(sa1, (char **)&sa, 10);
            unsigned long nb = strtoul(sb1, (char **)&sb, 10);

            if (na == nb) {
                if ((sa - sa1) == (sb - sb1)) {
                    /* XXX should check for '.' */
                    continue;
                } else {
                    /* Perform regular strcmp to handle 0 :: 00 */
                    return strcmp(sa1, sb1);
                }
            } else {
                return (na < nb) ? -1 : +1;
            }
        } else {
            if (a == b) {
                if (a != '\0')
                    continue;
                else
                    return 0;
            } else {
                return (a < b) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your sorting algorithm, you may need to wrap it with an extra level of indirection:

```
int natural_string_cmp_ind(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return natural_string_cmp(*(const char * const *)p1, *(const char * const *)p2);
}


char *array[size];

... // array is initialized with filenames

qsort(array, size, sizeof(*array), natural_string_cmp_ind);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can play around with your data structure. For example instead of `vector<string>`, you can convert your data to `vector< pair<int, string> >`. Then `{"good_6", "good_7", "good_8"...,"good_660"}` should be  `{(6, "good"), (7, "good"), (7, "good")..., (660, "good")}`. In the end, you convert it back and do whatever you want.

Another way is just to define your own comparator to do the exact comparison as what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) to replace string "good_" with empty string, and use [stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) to convert the rest of the integral part of the string. Lets say the value obtained is `x`.

Create std::map and populate it in this way `myMap[x] = vec_element`.

Then you can traverse from `m.begin()` till `m.end()` to find sorted order.

Code:

```
myMap[ stoi( vec[i].replace(0,5,"") )] = vec[i];

for( MapType::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it ) {
    sortedVec.push_back( it->second );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're just having trouble with the sorting and not how you plan to change the names after you sort.

Something like this might work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    char buffer[64] = {};
    for (size_t i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "good_%d", i * 3);
        v.push_back(buffer);
        sprintf(buffer, "bad_%d", i * 2);
        v.push_back(buffer);
    }
    std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (const auto& s : v)
    {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), 
        [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) 
    {
        //This assumes a lot about the contents of the strings
        //and has no error checking just to keep things short.
        size_t l_pos = lhs.find('_');
        size_t r_pos = rhs.find('_');
        std::string l_str = lhs.substr(0, l_pos);
        std::string r_str = rhs.substr(0, r_pos);
        int l_num = std::stoi(lhs.substr(l_pos + 1));
        int r_num = std::stoi(rhs.substr(r_pos + 1));
        return std::tie(l_str, l_num) < std::tie(r_str, r_num);
    });
    std::cout << "-----\n";
    for (const auto& s : v)
    {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Managed to do it with the following compare function:

```
bool numericStringComapre(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    size_t foundUnderScore = s1.find_last_of("_");
    size_t foundDot = s1.find_last_of(".");
    string s11 = s1.substr(foundUnderScore+1, foundDot - foundUnderScore - 1);

    foundUnderScore = s2.find_last_of("_");
    foundDot = s2.find_last_of(".");
    string s22 = s2.substr(foundUnderScore+1, foundDot-foundUnderScore - 1);

    int i1 = stoi(s11);
    int i2 = stoi(s22);

    if (i1 < i2) return true;

    return false;
}
```

full file name was good_0.png, hence that find_last_of(".").